# Install programs in other directories

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a PC with a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HD. I want to have Ubuntu and Windows dual boot. I am OK with this bit. The problem is that I want to partition the SSD in 2 60GB partitions and have one for Ubuntu and one for Windows. Now in windows I can install all the programs in the 1TB drive. In Ubuntu I don't know if this is possible or how it is done.

First let me know if this is possible, easy to do and won't cause the system any malfunction. And then please, if it meets the criteria above, show me how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Ubuntu I don't know if this is possible or how it is done.

Yes, it is possible. It used to be custom to do so when you use a server version. Instead of changing the location for MySQL to store its database you can simply mount it elsewhere and share different operating  systems with the same MySQL installation by mounting /var/.

> First let me know if this is possible, easy to do and won't cause the system any malfunction.

Yes, yes and no. Yes, it is easy when you understand how. No it will not break anything.

> And then please, if it meets the criteria above, show me how it is done.

Now for the kicker: software installed in Ubuntu will go to directories like `/etc`, `/var/` and `/usr/`. If you create a partition on the 1Tb and call it `/etc/`, `/var/`,  `/usr/` all software in that directory will go to the 1Tb disc.

You can stop reading here if you understood this.

---

> **A bit more ...**

Problem you will face is that in Linux software is not installed into 1 directory with the name of that software as the root directory as in Windows. Software will be in directories bases on functionality. So binaries for admin tasks go to a (/usr)/sbin/. Normal binaries go to (/usr)/bin/. Every file has its location.

So if you put directories like ...

- /etc/
- /var/
- /sbin/
- /usr/
- /run/

onto their own partition on the 1Tb disk you will have almost all software on the 1Tb disk. Now it will depend on how you use your system to make this more suited for you. For instance: if you do not use apache and mysql /var/ is not needed.

---

Mind you. I would not bother at all with separating the system besides /home and maybe swap if you are worried about the life span of your SSD. I have a 120 SSD like you and put all but /home/ onto the SSD. Now if you need it for some serious server tasks, ok. You could make life easier backup wise to create different mount points. But the general idea for servers nowadays is also to not do this and just create 1 big partition called /.

---

> **My personal setup**

The stuff below this is subjective. We can argue about partition methods for years and years. Here is how I did it:

My setup (notebook with 120Gb HDD and 750Gb HDD. I have Ubuntu 14.10, Windows 7 (C: is on the SSD, D: is part of the HDD and Redhat (does not use the ssd) on it. The layout for Ubuntu:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:/$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        99G  6,7G   87G   8% /
none            4,1k     0  4,1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2,1G  4,1k  2,1G   1% /dev
tmpfs           413M  1,1M  412M   1% /run
none            5,3M  4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
none            2,1G   36M  2,1G   2% /run/shm
none            105M   62k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb5        25G  2,0G   22G   9% /home
/dev/sdb6       365G  284G   63G  83% /discworld
```

/discworld is my 2nd disc. As you can see I have a / that is less than 10% full so the space on my SSD is largely not used and my /home/ is almost empty. And I do not even bother with swap anymore.

Even with all the software I install I never get over 15Gb before Ubuntu gets a new release. The SSD has been in use for over a year now and it is still healthy. All the scare about it wearing out to me seems ... well ... stupid. Yes it might break someday but that is why all important stuff are on the HDD. But even that disk might day someday.

Comment: So basically you are saying: Partition the SSD one half for Ubuntu the other for Windows. And then Partition the HDD it lets say 300GB for ubuntu and 700 for windows (since i will use windows the most) and in the first 300GB I create directories named /etc /sbin /bin /usr /var and /run. When do i do this part? After i installed ubuntu or in the instalation procces while i split the discs?

Comment: During the installation process of Windows (since you will install that 1st) if the disks are empty. Create unallocated space on both disks for Ubuntu so Windows does not use that). Or if you have an operating system installed already from that operating system. "since i will use windows the most" Ubuntu is happy to mount an NTFS partition so that 300 might even be a lot. Those 700 from Windows you can also use in Ubuntu. (does not work the other way around though: Microsoft does not want you to see other operating systems.